# Can't find xml path from C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This question must be easy, but I faced a problem, which I can't deal with.
No matter what I try I am unable to parse this xml with linq and get the full-path value.
The error is "Can't find the path."

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"All.xml");
```

![enter image description here][1]
How can I resolve it ?
And How can I get xml info in C#?

thanks

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<content contentType="REPLY">
   <submitInfo> 
    <setting name="a1" info ="openit" path ="examplefin.c"  serializeAs="String">
      <add name="a11" value="example1.c"/>
      <add name="a12" value="example2.c"/>
      <value />  
    </setting>

  </submitInfo> 
</content>
```

code:

```
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("All.xml");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"All.xml");
            reader.Read();

            //get setting info
            var qname = from xElement in doc.Element("submitInfo").Elements("")
                        from p in doc.Element("setting").Elements("")
                        select p;

            foreach (var t1 in qname)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t1 + "");
            }

            var qqname = from q in qname
                         where q.Attribute("name").Value == "setting"
                         select q.Attribute("info","path");

            foreach (var t2 in qqname)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t2 + "");
            }

            //get add info
            var qqqname = from p in qname
                         where p.Attribute("name").Value == "add"
                         select p.Attribute("value");

            foreach (var t3 in qqqname)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t3 + "");
            }
```

Comment: "How can I get xml info in C#?" Could you clarify what exactly you *want* to get from the file, and which parts of your code aren't working to do that?

Comment: Since you're not using the full path to the file, have you verified that `XMLFile.xml` exists in the current working directory?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I want get xml text and show it

Comment: @JeffMercado this xml file is in c# ，I can use "Relative path" ?

Comment: And it seems that this relative path isn't what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error is "Can't find the path."

First: You don't need XmlReader anymore because of XDocument. See the attached image:

If your xml file cannot be loaded successfully, please make sure that your xml file is where your exe file locates (Please just set the xml file "Copy To Local"= true).

[image]

### Plz choose "Copy if newer（如果较新则复制）"

If there's anything wrong with your xml file's analyse, please:

```
var qname = from xElement in doc.Element("submitInfo").Elements()
                        from p in doc.Element("setting").Elements()
                        select p;
```

Notice that "Elements" don't have an empty string, because this means you will read the element's name (No xml tag name is empty!):

And as for your real xml content, please change to this following:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile.xml");

//get all the sub elemens under the "setting" tag:

var qnames = from p in doc.Element("submitInfo").Element("setting").Elements("add")
             select p;
   foreach(var add in qnames)
{
   ………………
}

  var settingElement = doc.Element("submitInfo").Element("setting");  //Get the "setting" element.

//get "value" tag
var valueElement = doc.Element("submitInfo").Element("setting").Element("value");
```

Comment: I can't get xml path

Comment: @sally: Please copy your xml file where your exe or executable program is.

Comment: I copy it 
it Can run
thanks

I want to Ask can I use "Relative path"?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your first issue, that's a matter of file placement and I can't really tell you much aside from that you need to make sure your file is in the `bin\debug` or `bin\release` folders (or whatever your working directories are).

As for reading the XML, you could just parse it all to anonymous types and use those. That might be easier. Concrete types have advantages too, if you want to bother with them.

```
var file = XElement.Load(path);
var submitInfos = file.Elements("submitInfo")
                      .Select(submitInfo =>
                              {
                                  Settings = submitInfo.Elements("setting")
                                                       .Select(setting =>
                                                               {
                                                                   name = setting.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                                   info = setting.Attribute("info").Value,
                                                                   path = setting.Attribute("path").Value,
                                                                   serializeAs = setting.Attribute("serializeAs").Value,
                                                                   values = setting.Elements("add")
                                                                                   .ToDictionary(c => c.Attribute("name").Value, c => c.Attribute("value").Value)
                                                               })
                              });
```

This hasn't been compiled, of course, but it should get you started. You can then use this in an intuitive way.